# Asking ffmpeg to extract frames at the original frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

On the FFmpeg documentation ([here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg), and [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC9)) I read that, by default, `FFmpeg` chooses to extract frames at 25 frames per second (otherwise you can specify a framerate with the `-r` option)

My problem is that I have a folder with dozens of videos, each of them recorded at different frame rates, so my question is:

Is there a way to ask `FFmpeg` to extract frames from a video at the **"native"** frame rate (i.e. the original frame rate at which the video was recorded)?

In case it matters, I am working with `MP4` files

Comment: This is a better answer to this question which doesn't require specifying a framerate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420985/ffmpeg-not-extracting-all-the-frames-from-a-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the original frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\sfps'
```

Example Output:

```
25 fps
```

You can futher pipe it to sed `... | sed 's/\sfps//'` to keep only the `25`, and store it into a variable, so you can use that variable to convert the videos e.g. `ffmpeg -r $originalFps`.

`grep -o` will extract the match, instead of the whole line containing the match.

`[0-9]\{1,3\}`  will match one to three digits

`\sfps` will match a white space followed by 'fps'

Comment: Thanks Eric. For some reason I can't `grep` the output of `ffmpeg`. I tried with and without `2>&1`. It's as if the output that I get on my terminal from `ffmpeg` is not pipeable (other commands are pipeable though)

Comment: Nevermind, I think it's working now. What is the purpose of the redirection `2>&1`? I have seen it before. Do you know why it is needed for `ffmpeg`?

Comment: @intrpc grep cannot parse `stderr` so you need the redirection, alternatively you can use `|&` instead of `2>&1`

Comment: By the way, just to clarify, on my machine `ffmpeg` (version SVN-r14102) does not output the frame rate in a substring following the syntax `# fps`. Instead I get something like `29.92 tb(r)`. Still, parsing the output by piping into grep can still be used for this, as you point out. By the way, another small question, why do I need `\s` mean in a regexp like this? I managed to get the output with just `grep -o '[0-9.]\{1,5\} tb(r)'` (i.e. having an actual space in the regexp)