# FFMPEG not extracting all the frames from a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract all the frames from a video in order to get some training data for a tensor flow project. However whenever I run

```
ffmpeg -i one.mp4 -r 1/1 "$filename%03d.jpeg"
```

I only get 15 pictures. My phone films in 30fps, and the video was 13 seconds long, so shouldn't I get roughly 490 pictures?

Is there an error in my understanding or am I using the wrong function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've added an output frame rate of `1`, so FFmpeg will pick one frame out of every second of the input. You want all frames with no drops or duplicates, so use

```
ffmpeg -i one.mp4 -vsync 0 "$filename%03d.jpeg"
```